# Why do double-quote change the result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a simple linux script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `ls $1`
do
       echo $i
done
```

In my temp folder are 4 file: a.a, a.aa, a.ab and a.ac

When i call ./script temp/*.?? i get:

```
temp/a.aa
```

When i call ./script "temp/*.??" i get:

```
temp/a.aa
temp/a.ab
temp/a.ac
```

Why do the double quote change the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case the shell expands `temp/*.??` to:

```
temp/a.aa temp/a.ab temp/a.ac
```

Since you are only looking at the first parameter in your script only `temp/a.aa` is passed to ls.

In the second case, the shell does not perform any expansion because of the quotes and the script receives the single argument `temp/*.??` which is expanded in the call to `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

Because without the quotes the shell is expanding your call to:

```
./script temp/a.aa temp/a.ab temp/a.ac
```

So `$1` is `temp/a.aa` instead of `temp/*.??`.